# Instantiate objects at spawn points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I am beginner in unity. I'm having a problem on instantiating a prefab. The problem in my code is after I click the accept button in my quest panel or the quest has been accepted, the object will spawn too many (endless loop *i don't know what is called*). I successfully spawn objects to their corresponding points. How can I spawn multiple prefab once? I am not sure if it's to be called on update method.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class SpawnFlower : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject flowers;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public float spawnTime = 1.5f;

    public int maxCount;

    void Update() {
        //InvokeRepeating ("SpawnFlowers", spawnTime, spawnTime);
        if(QuestManager.questManager.RequestAcceptedQuest(1)) {
            SpawnFlowers ();
        }
    }

    public void SpawnFlowers() {
        List<Transform> freeSpawnPoints = new List<Transform>(spawnPoints);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++) {
            if (freeSpawnPoints.Count <= 0)
                return;
            int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0, freeSpawnPoints.Count);
            Transform pos = freeSpawnPoints [spawnIndex];
            freeSpawnPoints.RemoveAt (spawnIndex);
            Instantiate (flowers, pos.position, pos.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that RequestAcceptedQuest(1) keeps returning true

Comment: Instantiate under a parent and check the child count in your function. Or use another counter to check if spawned at correct amount.